# when stack overflow happens

Tags: c++, memory, stack

When I run program like:

```
int main()
{
    int A[600000];
    return 0;
}
```

I get windows error "the program has stopped working" after running but when:

```
int main()
{
    int A[500000];
    int B[500000];
    return 0;
}
```

Everything seems to be okay. Is it because stack is overflowed in first example? I used to think variables in each function are put at the same stack but I am probably wrong. Is it possible to create too many objects in function to handle and when is too many?

Comment: Yes, most operating systems impose a limit on the stack size. On unix-like OSes you can use `ulimit` to change that limit. However unless you clarify what "it comes up with errors" actually is, all you'll get is speculation.

Comment: Note that I have no problem running either program in Linux. And NO, it is NOT going to place B on the heap by magic.

Comment: “It comes up with errors after running” What errors?

Comment: Please consider updating question title to convey meaning more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, you overflowed the stack reserve size (at least in visual studio terms). The stack reserve size is related to the memory size of a single variable, you simply hit the limit in the first snippet.

If you are using Visual Studio, then you can change the stack reserve size in the project properties:

Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> Stack Reserve Size

Comment: If you have only 1 stack per thread why it is not overflowed in the second example?

Comment: It sounds like your talking about the call stack which is different. The Call Stack is about function calls, which you can see in the call stack window on Visual Studio. You can overflow the call stack too, and you can also increase the call stack size.


There is nothing that stops you from writing code like in your second snippet, no stack problems of any kind. You could probably write the array variable dozens more times until the program fails, but that will most likely be a out of memory error (your RAM).

Comment: So a thread have a fixed size call stack for function calls, and each variable or array has it's own fixed size stack to be placed in ? Sorry if it sounds ridiculous or something but I am getting confused

Comment: It is pretty much just that, heres another explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables

Answer (score 2):

The wording *"It comes up with errors **after running**"* surprises me since run-time errors related to the memory limits of the environment (such as stack overflow or the machine's memory being maxed out) would be just the same for both of your sample codes.

I was able to reproduce it only with size `600 000 000`, i.e.:

```
int main()
{
    int A[600000000];
}
```

which on a 32-bit platform is a non-sense that is being stopped by the compiler already:

> error: size of array ‘A’ is too large"

since it is an attempt of creating a memory block of size bigger than 2GB that could not be addressable on a 32-bit platform... while 2 arrays of size `500 000 000` are allowed in this case:

```
int main()
{
    int A[500000000];
    int B[500000000];
}
```

A reasonable thing to do here is to simply avoid allocating big memory blocks on a stack and just place it on a heap. For example using the already mentioned `std::vector` that itself would reside on a stack yet manage its internal storage on the heap:

```
std::vector<int> v(600000);
```

which in this case yields a memory block of size around 2.3MB being allocated on a heap.